# Structure containing more than one integer gives Runtime Error

Tags: c, structure, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The code contains a structure for binary search tree. When I remove elements - checkLeft or checkRight from bstNode structure or don't store any value in theses variables in createTree method, then it works properly

I want to store values in all the three variables data, checkLeft and checkRight. How to solve this. Code can be found here http://ideone.com/geIfLk

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct bstNode
 {
     int data;
     struct bstNode *right, *left;
     int checkLeft, checkRight;
 };

 void addBSTNode(struct bstNode *temp, struct bstNode **root)
 {
     if(*root == NULL)
     {
         *root = temp;
         return;
     }

     struct bstNode *current = *root;
     while(1)
     {
         if(temp->data > current->data && current->right != NULL)
             current = current->right;
         else if(temp->data < current->data && current->left != NULL)
             current = current->left;
         else
             break;
     }

     if(temp->data > current->data)
         current->right = temp;
     else
         current->left = temp;

 }

 struct bstNode* createTree(int dataArray[], int size)
 {
     struct bstNode *temp, *root = NULL;
     int count = 0;
     while(count < size)
     {
         temp = (struct bstNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode*));
         temp->data = dataArray[count++];
         temp->checkLeft = 0;
         temp->checkRight = 0;
         temp->right = NULL;
         temp->left = NULL;
         addBSTNode(temp, &root);
     }

     return root;
 }

 int main(void) 
 {

     int dataArray[] = {4,1,3,2,5,8,7,6,9};
     struct bstNode *root = createTree(dataArray, 9);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I doubt this is c# looks like c++

Comment: Not a homework, trying some random question on data structure.

Comment: Also, "gives error" is a poor description. **what** error?

Comment: Errors? What errors? compiler errors? Linker errors? Runtime errors? Please include more information about the errors (as complete and unedited as possible) in your question.

Comment: Okay, runtime errors. Now edit your question to include that information. Then run your program in a debugger, and when the runtime error (crash I suppose?) happens the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. There you can examine the function call stack, to see where in your code (if not already there) the problem is. Please edit your question to include that information as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line

```
 temp = (struct bstNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode*));
```

you allocate memory for a bstNode pointer instead of the whole struct. What you want is to allocate the whole struct, which is `malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode));` This also explains why it works when you remove some members of the struct. At some point the size of `bstNode` and `bstNode*` is identical, or et least does not lead to immediate errors.

See [here](http://ideone.com/4hxH1w) for the edited example.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I never realised this mistake. I always use to allocate as malloc(sizeof(struct bstNode*)); and also this thing works when only one integer is defined/used.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in `addBSTNode` if `tmp->data` is neither above nor below `current->data` and both left and right pointers are not `NULL`?

The execution flow goes out of the `while` loop and reaches the second series of `if` statements, which will pick the second `if` there: `tmp` will overwrite the left pointer, even though there could be something there already.

A simple fix is to replace `temp->data < current->data` by `temp->data <= current->data` so that search will effectively reach a leaf before breaking out of the while loop.